# VK market API market.add (photo not found or already assigned to another item)

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Загружаю изображения в основной альбом группы, получаю айдишники изображений, использую метод market.add.

Вот пример параметров, передаваемых методу:

```
2016-01-11 12:32:57:
Array
(
    [owner_id] => -111326041
    [name] => Свеча (477)
    [description] => http://work01.covoxx.ru/shop2/product/svecha-477/\n Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce luctus posuere augue. Maecenas mattis venenatis metus sit amet fermen
    [category_id] => 1
    [price] => 1014
    [main_photo_id] => 397973200
)
```

Вроде все верно. Что я делаю не так? Фото загружено, его видно в альбоме. Вот такой респонс мне приходит:

```
2016-01-11 12:32:57:
Array
(
[error] => Array
    (
        [error_code] => 100
        [error_msg] => One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: photo not found or already assigned to another item
        [request_params] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => oauth
                        [value] => 1
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => method
                        [value] => market.add.json
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => api_id
                        [value] => 5220505
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => category_id
                        [value] => 1
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => description
                        [value] => http://work01.covoxx.ru/shop2/product/svecha-477/\n Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce luctus posuere augue. Maecenas mattis venenatis met
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => main_photo_id
                        [value] => 397973200
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => name
                        [value] => Свеча (477)
                    )

                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => owner_id
                        [value] => -111326041
                    )

                [8] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => price
                        [value] => 1014
                    )

                [9] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => random
                        [value] => 5869
                    )

                [10] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => timestamp
                        [value] => 1452504777
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Картинки не присвоены никаким другим объектам, они реально существуют и открываются по ссылке:

```
2016-01-11 12:32:57:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pid] => 397973200
            [id] => photo3994821_397973200
            [aid] => 226742674
            [owner_id] => -111326041
            [user_id] => 3994821
            [src] => http://cs631121.vk.me/v631121821/cd53/aYKTVHJ8UTc.jpg
            [src_big] => http://cs631121.vk.me/v631121821/cd54/7OM_dsKa4OQ.jpg
            [src_small] => http://cs631121.vk.me/v631121821/cd52/lTe3oLf6ezk.jpg
            [width] => 300
            [height] => 300
            [text] =>.
            [created] => 1452504883
        )

)
```

Comment: Удалось всё таки решить данную проблему? Столкнулся с тем же.. выдает ту же ошибку и никак больше не регирует на добавление

Comment: @Михаил, а ответ прочитать - не вариант?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сбило с толку то, что в [описании товарного API](https://vk.com/dev/market) вконтакта нет специальных методов для загрузки фото. Поэтому воспользовался стандартными методами загрузки изображений в группу, а этого было делать никак нельзя. Для загрузки изображений товаров нужно использовать вот эту [инструкцию](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0). Там все доступно изложено. Правда из-за сырости API есть куча нюансов и недоделок. Думаю все это в ближайшее время исправят.